# Mapnik ignoring my lat long bounding box

Tags: gis, mapnik

Can anyone see anything wrong with the following set of commands? Every time I run these image.png is a image of the UK and not the JOSM map I exported. I'm guessing there's something awry with the db import however the output mentions that it's processing my coords and data.

Steps:

1 - Exported a .osm file from JOSM or Merkaator.

2 - Imported into psql using the following command:

```
osm2pgsql -m -d gis -S ~/mapnik/default.style -b 103,1.3,104,1.4 ion.osm  -v -c
```

The output for this looks like:

```
    marshall@ubuntu:~/mapnik$ osm2pgsql -m -d gis -S ~/mapnik/default.style -b 103,1.3,104,1.4 ion.osm  -v -c
osm2pgsql SVN version 0.66-

Using projection SRS 900913 (Spherical Mercator)
Applying Bounding box: 103.000000,1.300000 to 104.000000,1.400000
Setting up table: planet_osm_point
Setting up table: planet_osm_line
Setting up table: planet_osm_polygon
Setting up table: planet_osm_roads
Mid: Ram, scale=100

Reading in file: ion.osm
Processing: Node(25k) Way(3k) Relation(0k)
Node stats: total(25760), max(844548651)
Way stats: total(3783), max(69993379)
Relation stats: total(27), max(536780)

Writing way(3k)

Writing rel(0k)
Committing transaction for planet_osm_point
Sorting data and creating indexes for planet_osm_point
Committing transaction for planet_osm_line
Committing transaction for planet_osm_roads
Sorting data and creating indexes for planet_osm_line
Committing transaction for planet_osm_polygon
Sorting data and creating indexes for planet_osm_roads
Sorting data and creating indexes for planet_osm_polygon
Completed planet_osm_polygon
Completed planet_osm_roads
Completed planet_osm_point
Completed planet_osm_line
```

I can see the correct lat/lon coords being passed in, I'm not sure how to verify this within the database

3 - `./generate_xml.py  --accept-none --dbname gis --symbols ./symbols/  --world_boundaries ../world_boundaries/`

4 - `./generate_image.py`

At this point image.png is a map of the UK, not Singapore which I have specified.

Can anyone see anything wrong with this? This is with mapnik 0.71 on ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

The issue is that the generate_image.py script does not read the data from the database but rather has it hardcoded inside. I'm not sure the reasoning behind this.

The solution is to edit generate_image.py manually and change the relevant line:

```
ll = (103,1.3,104,1.4)
```